# How to run Cargo in Vim?

Tags: rust, vim, rust-cargo, neovim

I want to run Rust code with a keybinding such as `<F5>`.

I tried the command `:!cargo run --bin %`, but in that case the `%` equals to `src/bin/test.rs`, instead of the wanted filename without suffix (which is `test`).

So how could I edit the command to cater to my needs?

Comment: "I want to do something with the filename" ==> "I do `:help filename<C-d>` to see what are my options before asking random internet users" ==> "hmm… `filename-modifiers` looks interesting" ==> "I read it" ==> "I solve my problem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the vim help on filename-modifiers you can get the file name without path & extension by appending `:t:r` to the % register
so

```
:!cargo run --bin %:t:r
```

will run the binary of the current file for single file binaries.
If you need the last directory name (multi file binaries) you can use

```
:!cargo run --bin %:h:t
```